# Querying to linq and displaying it to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, model-view-controller

I have a table called **CURRENCY** :

```
-------------------------
|  Id  |  CurrencyName  |
|   1  |        USD     |
|   2  |        EUR     |
|   3  |        JPY     |
-------------------------
```

And then I have another table called **SALES**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Id   |   Sales   |     TransactionDate    |    CurrencyID  |
|   1   |   5000    |        11/25/2016      |          1     |
|   2   |   3000    |        11/25/2016      |          1     |
|   3   |   4000    |        11/26/2016      |          2     |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to output the table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  TransactionDate   |      USD      |      EUR    |     JPY    |
|      11/25/2016    |      8000     |        0    |      0     |
|      11/26/2016    |        0      |      4000   |      0     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure where to start. I'm really new to `MVC` and `LINQ` so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Do you need the currencies columns dynamic? What happens if tomorrow there's another currency supported?

Comment: Yes it is dynamic. That's why it's has a separate table for currencies.

Comment: *'m not sure where to start.* Well, not Stack Overflow. Mybe you'll get a fish here if you're lucky, not a fishing rod. Find an online tutorial on LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's best optimized for performance, but it does the job.
It uses 2 `GroupBy` methods. One to group by the `TransactionDate` and one to group together the currencies.

I guess it can be optimized with a `Dictionary` or a `Lookup`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var currencies = new List<CurrencyRecord>
        {
            new CurrencyRecord {Id = 1, Name = "USD"},
            new CurrencyRecord {Id = 2, Name = "EUR"},
            new CurrencyRecord {Id = 3, Name = "JPY"}
        };

        var sales = new List<SalesRecord>
        {
            new SalesRecord {Id = 1, Sales = 5000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), CurrencyId = 1},
            new SalesRecord {Id = 2, Sales = 3000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-25"), CurrencyId = 1},
            new SalesRecord {Id = 3, Sales = 4000, TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-11-26"), CurrencyId = 2}
        };

        var result = sales.GroupBy(sale => sale.TransactionDate,
            (key, values) =>
                new
                {
                    Key = key,
                    Sales = values.GroupBy(v => v.CurrencyId, (c, values2) => new {CurrencyId = c, SumSales = values2.Sum(v2 => v2.Sales)})
                });

        Console.Write("Date\t\t");
        foreach (CurrencyRecord currency in currencies) {
            Console.Write($"{currency.Name}\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var record in result) {
            Console.Write($"{record.Key.ToShortDateString()}\t");
            foreach (CurrencyRecord currency in currencies)
            {
                var sum = record.Sales.Where(s => s.CurrencyId == currency.Id).Select(s => s.SumSales).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Single();
                Console.Out.Write($"{sum}\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class CurrencyRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SalesRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```